# How do I put my Body group into my Armature group?

Tags: armature, groups

This is what my groups currently look like

[image]

This is what I'd like them to look like

[image]

I've tried simply clicking and dragging the Body onto the Armature text in hopes that the Body would go into that folder with no luck.

If anyone could help me find the answer I'm looking for I would appreciate it.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy in the outliner represents the hierarchy of the objects. Child objects are grouped below their parent in the dropdown style.

Next to manipulating the hierarchy in the outliner, you can simply go into the 3D view, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the *Body* object, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the armature and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open up the parenting menu. In the parenting menu chose *Object*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to click and drag the ICON next to the group name. Not the TEXT.

Click and drag the ICON of the group onto the other group.